# specify parameters in odoo module

Tags: odoo-11

I'm using odoo 11, and I'm trying to create a module. I added `web_google_maps` to the `depends` tag in my `__manifest__.py`, but I'm supposed to specify some parameters, such as: google_maps_view_api_key, google_maps_lang_localization, google_maps_region_localization, google_maps_theme.

Where can I specify them?

Comment: You want to add these arguments at the time of installation of module ? or you can  add that later on ?

Comment: @KevalMehta at this time I need to add it in the installation, but I would appreciate very much both solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special model in Odoo for specifying configuration/system parameters. The technical name is `ir.config_parameter`. You can simply create one of these parameters in an xml file as a record.

Below is an example:

```
<record id="google_maps_view_api_key" model="ir.config_parameter">
   <field name="key">google_maps_view_api_key</field>
   <field name="value">my value here</field>
</record>
```

You can access the above parameter in code with the following:

```
self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('google_maps_view_api_key')
```

It works on a key, value pair methodology. The key is the parameter, value is the value of that parameter.

Alternatively, if you'd like to create them manually through the Odoo front end, you can navigate to "Settings -> Technical -> System Parameters" and create the record there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`post_init_hook`** argument in `__manifest__.py` file which allows you to insert your required argument at the time of installation of any app. This might be useful for you. You can refer following link: [Odoo document for all the arguments in for manifest file](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/module.html)